# Set Visual C++ no conformance (permissive) mode in C++ 20 from cmake

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

My code depends on code which I cannot modify, and which requires permissive (`/permissive`) to compile.

I use cmake as a build tool, and attempt to provide the permissive flag like so:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_compile_options(/permissive)
```

However, the compile command invoked by cmake adds the `-std:c++latest` parameter **after** `/permissive`, which in effect turns off permissive mode (documented [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/#c-language-modes-and-compatibility-guarantees)).

Is there something I can do cause cmake to override the implied `/permissive-` from `-std:c++latest`?

Comment: If the code can be compiled as a library you can set c++ standard and compilation options per target with [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) and [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html)

Comment: Ah, I should have clarified that even the headers require permissive mode, so I need to enable that for code that I want to compile with c++ standard 20

Comment: I believe this is a shortcoming in Visual Studio 2019. Upgrading to 2022 resolved it, and using the instructions above now let's me set permissive mode